# SQL Table Joins - repeated row entries and possibly two joins needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables:

ZE:

```
Zone LandUse
101  Uni
102  Mall
103  Gym
104  Uni
105  Residential
```

Uni_Distribution:

```
Zone Distribution
1    0.1
2    0.2
3    0.3
4    0.4
5    0.1
```

I would like to join these tables to give the following (calls only the Zone IDs for the Land Use named `University`):

```
Origin Destination Distribution
101    1           0.1
101    2           0.2
101    3           0.3
101    4           0.4
101    5           0.1
1      101         0.1
2      101         0.2
3      101         0.3
4      101         0.4
5      101         0.1
104    1           0.1
104    2           0.2
104    3           0.3
104    4           0.4
104    5           0.1
1      104         0.1
2      104         0.2
3      104         0.3
4      104         0.4
5      104         0.1
```

That is, I would like to be able to join these two tables in a way that I can use the Zone IDs from each table as two separate columns where I need the `ZE.Zone` to be repeated down for each unique row of the `Uni_Distribution` table. I also need the query to only use the Zone IDs from table `ZE` when Land Use is `University`.

I have tried the following query as a start to just get part of the table, however I am not getting what I want at this stage (Mostly NULL values for Origin).

```
SELECT
    ZE.[Zone] AS Origin,
    U.[Zone] AS Destination,
    U.[Distribution]
FROM ZE
RIGHT JOIN [dist].[University_Distribution] AS U
    ON U.Zone = ZE.[Zone]
```

Comment: What is the actual relationship (specifically join condition) between the two tables?

Comment: I think I need to use union instead? My query seems completely wrong as there is no relationship. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you basically want a `cross join`:

```
SELECT ZE.[Zone] as Origin, U.[Zone] as Destination, U.[Distribution]
FROM ZE CROSS JOIN
     [dist].[University_Distribution] U 
WHERE ZE.land_use = 'UNI';
```

This only does half of what you want.  For the complete solution, you also need `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT ZE.[Zone] as Origin, U.[Zone] as Destination, U.[Distribution]
FROM ZE CROSS JOIN
     [dist].[University_Distribution] U 
WHERE ZE.land_use = 'UNI'
UNION ALL
SELECT U.[Zone] as Destination, ZE.[Zone] as Origin, U.[Distribution]
FROM ZE CROSS JOIN
     [dist].[University_Distribution] U 
WHERE ZE.land_use = 'UNI';
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed - Cross join! Thank you :)